# visual studio vb debug css style from <style></style> not rendering

Tags: css, vb.net, debugging, web, visual-studio-2013

```
<style>
 #ctrtable{width:600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
</style>
```

Web page has the above style block above to to center table on viewport

When in VisStudio 2013 express running in debug mode css does not render, table is aligned left. However, if I copy and paste the style to an inline style="", the table is rendered in center

???

tom

Answer (score 0):

when defining a style in this way:

```
<style>
  #ctrtable{width: 600px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
</style>
```

You implement the style in this way:

```
<table id="ctrtable">
  <tr>
    <td>something</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

when defining a style in this way:

```
<style>
  .ctrtable{width: 600px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
</style>
```

You implement the style in this way:

```
<table class="ctrtable">
  <tr>
    <td>something</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Try this sample

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      .cntrtable{text-align: center;} 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <td><table class="cntrtable" style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #FF0000;"><tr><td>table-1</td></tr></table></td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td><table class="cntrtable" style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #00FF00;"><tr><td>table-2</td></tr></table></td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td><table class="cntrtable" style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #0000FF;"><tr><td>table-3</td></tr></table></td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td><table class="cntrtable" style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #FF00FF;"><tr><td>table-4</td></tr></table></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I specifically wanted a class, because I have several tables which I want to ctr. in the table element I included class='ctrtable'. The problem is not a mixing of style definition

Comment: If you want to use the style in multiple tables you must declare the style starting with a PERIOD (.crttable) and if you wish to use the style in a single table then you would use the HASH (#crttable) the difference being in the table ID see my sample code above for reference.